# pdo_pgsql is not enabled on runtime vercel-php@0.6.0

Tags: php, postgresql, vercel

I trying to get data from my postgres database on php (with laravel) using vercel, but the "pdo_pgsql" is not enabled on php.ini. When i call my api route return error.

Error on call api route:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4tD6.png)

My php.ini config:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN9cH.png)

Runtimes php.ini config:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueZQS.png)

Runtimes link to explore:
https://github.com/vercel-community/php/tree/master

I trying to resolve this hours, please anybody help me

Try list:

- Change runtimes version, in all versions pdo_pgsql is disabled for me, but in examples all runtimes this options is enabled;
- Remove laravel framework and run only pure php, but not work;
- Remove options on vercel.json, nothing results too.

Comment: I'm struggling to connect a vercel postgreSql db to my laravel project as well

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to vercel-php@0.6.1 may be the best solution as pgsql is enabled in this version.